# Calling a module function in a ruby module

Tags: ruby, module

I want to call a module function to define a constant in a utility module in ruby. However, when I try this I get an error message. Here comes the code and the error:

```
module M
  ABC = fun

  module_function

  def self.fun
    "works"
  end
end
```

Error message:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `fun' for M:Module
```

Any ideas? I also tried it without `self` and with `M.fun` but no success...

Comment: So you want to set the value for constant `ABC` using the result of method `fun`, isn't it?

Comment: correct. I want it computed once and never changed again. So ideally, I would put a freeze on it, but that would complicate the current question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just that the method is not defined when you assign `fun` to `ABC`. Just change the order:

```
module M
  def self.fun
    "works"
  end

  ABC = fun
end

M::ABC
#=> "works"
```

If you dislike the order (constants below methods), you might want to consider to have the method itself to memorize its return value. A common pattern looks like:

```
module M
  def self.fun
    @cached_fun ||= begin
      sleep 4     # complex calculation
      Time.now    # return value
    end
  end
end

M.fun
# returns after 4 seconds => 2017-03-03 23:48:57 +0100
M.fun
# returns immediately => 2017-03-03 23:48:57 +0100
```

Comment: wow, that is weird. I don't need to define private methods before I use them in a class. So why do I need to do it in a module?

Comment: Because constants are assigned when the Ruby files is loaded. Whereas methods call other methods at runtime, after the file was loaded.

Comment: ok, so basically no way to define the constants first (which is the main information, that I want on top) and the methods later.

Comment: @bln-tom: Why is that weird? You call the method on line 2, at which point the method definition on line 6 hasn't even been parsed yet, let alone executed. How could Ruby possibly know what code to execute, if it hasn't even parsed the definition yet; it can't time-travel into the future? This is the same with private methods, by the way. If you call them before they are defined, that won't work either.

Comment: @JörgWMittag To be more precise I meant private methods of classes. In this case, it is totally fine to first write public methods and then private methods. I even consider it a good practice, since the public interface of the class is what you see when you open the file.

Answer (score 2):

Test this in you `irb` console:

```
$ irb 
2.3.3 :001 > module M
2.3.3 :002?>   def self.fun
2.3.3 :003?>     "worked"
2.3.3 :004?>   end
2.3.3 :005?>   
2.3.3 :006 >   ABC = fun
2.3.3 :007?> end
 => "worked" 
2.3.3 :008 > M
 => M 
2.3.3 :009 > M::ABC
 => "worked" 
2.3.3 :010 >
```

The fact is that now you defined `self.fun` before using it.

In your code you used the method before defining it.

Comment: basically the same answer. I voted for the faster one, sorry.

Comment: Sure! I was probably typing when he posted. But the important part is that your question was answered.